# Highlight a row if one of four values is met

Tags: microsoft-excel

My spreadsheet can be up to 300+ rows per month, 12 Sheets one for each month.
I would like to highlight the entire row when it matches any of the four main accts out of 100. For example acct. 12345, 23456, 34567, 56789

```
Acct    Pattern Tracking    Invoice Status

12345   A   2365987 1235698 C         Highlight this row in Blue

23456   B   2587451 1452689 C         Highlight this row in Blue

34567   C   2695365 1237896 T         Highlight this row in Blue

45678   B   2012013 1202020 C

56789   A   2362985 1478520 C         Highlight this row in Blue

45678   C   2014785 1236985 T

34567   D   2035641 1045297 T         Highlight this row in Blue

65986   E   2369852 1485797 C

56789   C   2313145 1025463 C         Highlight this row in Blue

47856   B   2020369 1056782 T

12345   C   2358796 1024396 C         Highlight this row in Blue
```

Thank You! in Advance

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to attach an image.

Answer (score 0):

The exact sequence depends on your version but it is basically the same.  This is 2013.

1. Highlight the whole range
2. Go to Conditional Formatting, New Rule
3. Choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. In the "Format values" field, put =$A1="12345"

This will highlight any row that has 12345 in column A.  The dollar makes sure that is is only column A that is tested for a match, but the whole row gets highlighted.

You can use standard formulas in the field, so use OR() to do the others, or set up multiple rules.

Comment: I have Excel 2010, I selected the entire range in my example (A2: e12) and used formula =$A1="12345" and nothing happened